# Textview setText from EditText in alert dialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-alertdialog, settext

- What's wrong with this code? The application has been stopped.

  ```
     public void names (View v) {
         AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
         alert.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null));
         alert.setTitle("Set players names");
         alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 TextView j=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                 TextView k=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                 EditText l=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.player1);
                 EditText m=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.player2);
                 String name1 = l.getText().toString();
                 String name2 = m.getText().toString();
                 j.setText(name1);
                 k.setText(name2);
             }
         });
         AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
         dialog.show();   
     }
  ```

  LogCat:

  06-08 18:07:20.613: D/libEGL(20332): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
     06-08 18:07:20.613: D/libEGL(20332): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
     06-08 18:07:20.623: D/libEGL(20332): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
     06-08 18:07:20.623: I/Adreno-EGL(20332): : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
     06-08 18:07:20.623: I/Adreno-EGL(20332): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
     06-08 18:07:20.623: I/Adreno-EGL(20332): Build Date: 12/01/13 Sun
     06-08 18:07:20.623: I/Adreno-EGL(20332): Local Branch: 
     06-08 18:07:20.623: I/Adreno-EGL(20332): Remote Branch: 
     06-08 18:07:20.623: I/Adreno-EGL(20332): Local Patches: 
     06-08 18:07:20.623: I/Adreno-EGL(20332): Reconstruct Branch: 
     06-08 18:07:20.673: D/OpenGLRenderer(20332): Enabling debug mode 0
     06-08 18:07:26.448: D/AndroidRuntime(20332): Shutting down VM
     06-08 18:07:26.458: W/dalvikvm(20332): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415898b0)
     06-08 18:07:26.458: E/AndroidRuntime(20332): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     06-08 18:07:26.458: E/AndroidRuntime(20332): java.lang.NullPointerException
     06-08 18:07:26.458: E/AndroidRuntime(20332):     at com.example.game.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:87)
     06-08 18:07:26.458: E/AndroidRuntime(20332):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:171)
     06-08 18:07:26.458: E/AndroidRuntime(20332):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     06-08 18:07:26.458: E/AndroidRuntime(20332):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
     06-08 18:07:26.458: E/AndroidRuntime(20332):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
     06-08 18:07:26.458: E/AndroidRuntime(20332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     06-08 18:07:26.458: E/AndroidRuntime(20332):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
     06-08 18:07:26.458: E/AndroidRuntime(20332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
     06-08 18:07:26.458: E/AndroidRuntime(20332):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
     06-08 18:07:26.458: E/AndroidRuntime(20332):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

  ```
  1. 

     06-08 18:15:27.578: D/AndroidRuntime(20809): Shutting down VM
             06-08 18:15:27.578: W/dalvikvm(20809): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415898b0)
             06-08 18:15:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(20809): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
             06-08 18:15:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(20809): java.lang.NullPointerException
             06-08 18:15:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(20809):     at com.example.game.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:92)
             06-08 18:15:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(20809):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:171)
             06-08 18:15:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(20809):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
             06-08 18:15:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(20809):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
             06-08 18:15:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(20809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
             06-08 18:15:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(20809):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
             06-08 18:15:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(20809):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
             06-08 18:15:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(20809):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
             06-08 18:15:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(20809):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
             06-08 18:15:27.578: E/AndroidRuntime(20809):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
             06-08 18:15:29.079: I/Process(20809): Sending signal. PID: 20809 SIG: 9
  ```

Comment: Please post the logcat error trace

Comment: +1, we need the logcat error trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be getting `NPE` on getting values from `EditText`

Try following :

```
final View myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_screen, null);
    alert.setView(myLayout);
    alert.setTitle("Set players names");

    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            TextView j=(TextView)myLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView k=(TextView)myLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            EditText l=(EditText)myLayout.findViewById(R.id.player1);
            EditText m=(EditText)myLayout.findViewById(R.id.player2);
            String name1 = l.getText().toString();
            String name2 = m.getText().toString();
            j.setText(name1);
            k.setText(name2);
            Log.i("j"+name1, "k"+name2);
        }
    });
```